# I have a problem with an id in onClick event JavaScript function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a little idle click game, but have a problem with my startIdle function.
I can't pass the id to which input progressbar that is needed to start counting.
I have one input field and one button foreach id from a obj.

```
function addRow(id) {
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.className = 'row';
div.innerHTML =
    '<div class="w3-blue" name="idle" id="'+id+'" style="height:24px;width:20%"></div>\
     <button onclick="startIdle('+id+')">Click me</button>';
document.getElementById('content').appendChild(div);
}

function startIdle(id) {
_counter = 1;
_timer = setInterval(function(){
    document.getElementById(id).style.width = (_counter + "%");
    _counter++;
    if(_counter > 100) clearInterval(_timer);
}, 100);
}

function createIdles(){
for (var key in money) {
    // skip loop if the property is from prototype
    if (!money.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
    var obj = money[key].id;
    addRow(obj)
}
}
createIdles()
```

this is the console.log I get:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: startIdle is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Comment: When you `console.log(obj)` in `createIdles`, what do you see?

Comment: You might consider using consistent indentation when writing code - it'll make reading and debugging it much easier, not only for potential answerers, but for you as well, when we can all see the `{` `}` blocks and their nesting level at a glance, rather than having to carefully pick through each line just to pick up on the logical paths.

Comment: Random thought, move startIdle above addRow ?

Comment: @AndyHoffman console.log outputs 1 2 5 10 20 and that is the ids that is meant to each line with input and button.

Comment: @MatthewPage same problem with the new order of the functions

Comment: Can you provide a link to your semi-functioning code?

Comment: i put the console.log(id) in startIdle(id) and it seems to not recieve the id from the onclick event

Comment: @AndyHoffman https://loggs.no/spill/idle/

Comment: when i check the elements in chrome i can see the id onclick="startIdle(1)", but its not working in the function startIdle()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that startIdle is defined inside a scope. Move it out of document.ready. Unless you can call the function from console, it isn't available globally.

Alternatively, building on Andy Hoffmans solution, bind onClick programmatically inside scope of document.ready, e.g.

```
document.querySelectorAll('button[data-id]')
   .forEach(elm => elm.addEventListener('click', 
     () => startIdle(elm.dataset.id)))
```

You can probably improve that a bit using jquery.

Comment: There's no indication that jQuery is installed or should be recommended.

Comment: @AndyHoffman, if you follow the link that you asked for, you'll see that he's using jQuery.

Comment: joint effort @AndyHoffman, I wouldn't have guessed the problem without the link you asked for :-)

Answer (score 0):

I removed the `onclick` attribute and perform binding separately. The binding and element lookup are done inside of a `setTimeout` to ensure the elements are present in the DOM when that code runs.

```js
// Note: I'm using a data-id attribute on the <button> so as to not 
// duplicate the id on the <div class="w-3">

function addRow(id) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.className = 'row';
  div.innerHTML =
    '<div class="w3-blue" name="idle" id="' + id + '" style="height:24px;width:20%"></div>\
     <button data-id="' + id + '">Click me</button>';
  document.getElementById('content').appendChild(div);
}

function startIdle() {
  // Remember the data-id attribute from above?
  alert('clicked ' + this.getAttribute('data-id'));
}

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  addRow(i);
}

// Bind click events in separate event loop to ensure elements are present in DOM
setTimeout(function() {
  var els = document.querySelectorAll("button[data-id]");

  els.forEach(function(el) {
    el.addEventListener("click", startIdle);
  })
});
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4mr02ktu/2/

Comment: This will get you the IDs inside of `startIdle`. I'm sure you can take it from there.